# How can we overlap two pie charts with same center in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to recreate the speedometer I have made here: https://sv.tiwari.cc/
Here is the code for it: https://github.com/sanskar-mk2/rcharts/blob/master/src/components/EfficiencyWeek.js#L60

I have created it in ReCharts at that time.

Now I have a sizeable codebase in ChartJS, so I am recreating the speedometer. Here is what I have achieved so far: [Chart JS Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvJ9H.png)

My problem is that if I use `radius` on the stick to make it larger than the dial, the arc is thrown off the center. So far, I have not found a way to center the stick while making it larger than the dial.

Thank you.

EDIT: I am including code as mentioned in comment, sorry it is my first time posting here:

```
    const chart6 = new Chart(ctx6, {
        type: "pie",
        data: {
            labels: [1, 2],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Efficiency",
                    data: [85, 10, 5],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        uniqolor("red").color,
                        uniqolor("orange").color,
                        uniqolor("green").color,
                    ],
                    borderColor: "#000000",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    order: 2,
                },
                {
                    circumference: 5,
                    label: "Actual Hours",
                    data: [100],
                    backgroundColor: uniqolor("abc").color,
                    borderColor: "#000000",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    order: 1,
                    weight: 3,
                    rotation: 76
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {
            rotation: 270,
            circumference: 180,
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: "end",
                    align: "end",
                    color: "#000000",
                },
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stacked: true,
                },
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

Comment: @AlonEitan, I have included my code so far, thank you for pointing it out.